# Entity framework will replace a newly added record , with a record created inside the action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, modelstate

I want to implement this simple scenario ,which I though EF will support out of the box.
I have a parent record named (Skill) and I am adding child records named (LinktoKB) to it. Now after adding a new LinktoKB, I want to return a view containing the up-to-date list of LinkToKBs (inclusing the newly added one).
Now my Post action method to add new LinktoKB is :-

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[CheckUserPermissions(Action = "Edit", Model = "Skill")]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddKBLink(AssignKBLinksToSkill assignkblinkToSkill)
{          
    try
    {

        if (assignkblinkToSkill.LinkToKB == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            unitofwork.SkillRepository.AddKBLinkToSkill(assignkblinkToSkill, unitofwork.StaffRepository.GetLoginUserName(User.Identity.Name));
            await unitofwork.Save();

            //i have removed the values from the model state to prevent showing validation error "that the URL and name is required after succfully adding a new link"
            // also to show the modified values and not the binded values

            string   oldlinkURL = assignkblinkToSkill.LinkToKB.URL;

            ModelState.Clear();

            var skillAfterAddingKBLink = await unitofwork.SkillRepository.FindSkill(assignkblinkToSkill.Skillid, r => r.LinkToKBs);
            assignkblinkToSkill.LinktoKBList = skillAfterAddingKBLink.LinkToKBs.ToList(); //get the new lsit from DB after addign the new link
            assignkblinkToSkill.LinkToKB.URL = "http://";//reset the values , so that user will not get old vlues
            assignkblinkToSkill.LinkToKB.Name = String.Empty;

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                TempData["Partialmessage"] = string.Format("{0} URL have been Added", oldlinkURL);


                return PartialView("AddKBLink", assignkblinkToSkill);
            }
            TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} URL have been Added", oldlinkURL);

            return View("AddKBLink", assignkblinkToSkill);
        }
    }
```

And my repository methods are:-

```
public async Task<Skill> FindSkill(int id, params Expression<Func<Skill, object>>[] includeProperties)    
{
    var query = context.Skills.AsQueryable();
    if (includeProperties != null || includeProperties.Count() != 0 || includeProperties[0].Name == "0")
        query = includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
    return await query.SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.SkillID == id);
}
```

&

```
public void AddKBLinkToSkill(AssignKBLinksToSkill assignKBLinkToSkill,string username)
{
    var skill = context.Skills.SingleOrDefault(a=>a.SkillID == assignKBLinkToSkill.Skillid);
    skill.LinkToKBs.Add(assignKBLinkToSkill.LinkToKB);
    skill.Modified = System.DateTime.Now;

    skill.ModifiedBy = staffrepo.GetUserIdByUserName(username);

    context.Entry(skill).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Currently I am getting a very strange behavior is that , the list that is returned to the view will not contain the newly added LinkToKB value and it will be replaced by the following value:-

```
assignkblinkToSkill.LinkToKB.URL = "http://"
```

so can anyone advice  on this please, although I am explicitly retrieving the LinkToKB list from database?

visual studio will how the following at two different stages:-

First this is the newly added LinkToKB:-

[image]

Second EF have replace it with the value inside the action method:-

[image]

I spend the whole day trying to understand what is going on ... and if i removed these lines:-

```
assignkblinkToSkill.LinkToKB.URL = "http://";//reset the values , so that user will not get old vlues
            assignkblinkToSkill.LinkToKB.Name = String.Empty;
```

i will get the new up-to-date list correctly (but i need them)..

I have two model classes (Skill & LinktoKB):-

```
public partial class Skill
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Skill()
        {
            this.SkillLevels = new HashSet<SkillLevel>();
            this.SkillLevelStaffs = new HashSet<SkillLevelStaff>();
            this.Customers = new HashSet<Customer>();
            this.LinkToKBs = new HashSet<LinkToKB>();
            this.SkillVersionHistories = new HashSet<SkillVersionHistory>();
            this.Skill1 = new HashSet<Skill>();
            this.Skills = new HashSet<Skill>();
        }

        public int SkillID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
       //code goes here 


        public virtual SkillStatu SkillStatu { get; set; }
        public virtual SkillType SkillType { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<LinkToKB> LinkToKBs { get; set; }

    }
```

{

```
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public LinkToKB()
    {
        this.Skills = new HashSet<Skill>();
    }

    public int LinkToKBID { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
}
```

and the following viewModel class:-

```
 public class AssignKBLinksToSkill
    {
     public ICollection<LinkToKB> LinktoKBList { set; get; }
     public LinkToKB LinkToKB { set; get; }
     public int Skillid { set; get; }

    }
```

Comment: This is confusing. What is the relation between `LinktoKBList`, `LinkToKBs` and `LinkToKB`?

Comment: @GertArnold sorry i did not include this from the beginning, i have updated my question with the 2 model classes & the view model

Answer (score 1):

In your code there's always one `assignkblinkToSkill.LinkToKB` instance. When it enters the method it's got some value that you store in the database. Later you re-assign its value to be `"http://"`.

But this is still the instance that you added to the list `skillAfterAddingKBLink.LinkToKBs`!

You only have to create a new instance in the view model:

```
assignkblinkToSkill.LinkToKB = new LinkToKB();
assignkblinkToSkill.LinkToKB.URL = "http://";
```

Comment: but still i can not understand the scenario, because inside the following link of code "assignkblinkToSkill.LinktoKBList = skillAfterAddingKBLink.LinkToKBs.ToList();" i am retrieving the LinkToKBs list from the database , so why EF have modified  the list? looks like it is a bug ?

Comment: Yes, that's true, but EF never overwrites local values by queries. The value is modified, so EF preserves this change. After all, you might want to save it (you don't, but EF doesn't know).